# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'load_module'

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller, kivy-language, kivymd

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "kivy\__init__.py", line 297, in <module>
```

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'load_module'`

**The Following line from** `kivy\__init__.py` **:**

**`mod = importer.find_module(modname).load_module(modname)`**

How to fix that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This means

```
importer.find_module(modname)
```

returns nothing.
Applying `.find_module(modname)` on `importer` object gave no result.

Comment: Should I change this line? how to make it work with exe file?

Comment: @yoavs put a `if` condition to check if the module exists or not, if it does, then load the module otherwise print it doesn't exist

Comment: for eg, `if importer.find_module(modname) != none: mod = importer.find_module(modname).load_module(modname)`

Comment: @yoavs I can't know from your code (you did show it at all) where is the problem.

Comment: This is __init__ file from the kivy module, I didnt wrote this